# Not able to access input text box value to code behind asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Here my page :

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms" Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>




        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnfromDate" Value="" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdntoDate" Value="" runat="server" />
        <div id="myModal1" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Issue Invoice</h4>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <form id="reused_form" runat="server">
                            <p>
                                Send invoice to...
                            </p>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name">
                                    To:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control"
                                    id="name" name="name" readonly maxlength="50" runat="server">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email">
                                    CC:</label>

                                <input type="email" ID="cc" class="form-control" runat="server" multiple>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <strong><i>Note:</i><small>&nbsp<i>The invoice can not be edited after issuing.</i></small></strong>
                            </div>


                            <asp:LinkButton CssClass="btn btn-warning m-btn btn-block btn-lg m-btn--custom m-btn--icon m-btn--air  " OnClick="Onbtn3_Click" Text="Issue Invoice " ID="LinkButton3" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
                        </form>
                        <div id="success_message" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: none;">
                            <h3>Sent your message successfully!</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div id="error_message"
                            style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: none;">
                            <h3>Error</h3>
                            Sorry there was an error sending your form.

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

In cs File i am trying to access email value using **cc.Value** as for email textbox id is cc. But it always gets empty string. In my default master page i have a form tag which runs at server so if i keep this modal in a form runat server then gives me error saying page can have only one form tag. Please can anyone help me out. Thanks in advance

Comment: tried with <asp:textbox id="email" runat="server"> and "email.Text" no use still value is empty string

Answer (score 0):

**This may help**
There is `Text` property available, so you can use `textBox.Text` to get textbox contian. In your case `cc.Text`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `textBox.text()`. Should work.

Answer (score 0):

As Html 5 type=“email” control is not available using runat attribute, you can access TextBox like below:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxCc" runat="server" TextMode="Email"></asp:TextBox>
```

Now in codebehind you can access it like txtBoxCc.Text

Also, you have to put it like below:

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack) {

    string cc = txtBoxCc.Text;
}
```

Comment: tried with <asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxCc" runat="server" TextMode="Email"></asp:TextBox> but no use

Comment: Did u put under !IsPostback

Comment: Also, can you change linkbutton to normal <asp:Button>

Comment: Check ViewState to see if its disabled